# CakePHP how to write a search form to display results

Tags: forms, cakephp

I am writing a search form in CakePHP 2.0, current I have set it up running with the index action and view (it also posts to the index action) with validation against the model so that if anything incorrect is entered into a search field (fields include date, price) there is a nice validation error message next to the element. Basically it is a bit like a scaffolded add form.

If validation is successful I need to actually run a query and return some data. I don't want to display this data in the index view - should I:

1. Run the query then render a different view (which means the URL doesn't change - not sure I want that).
2. Store the search parameters in a session, redirect off to another action then retrieve the search details.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Both options are ok. You must decide what you like more, to not change the url or to change it?

you may also use the named parameters to pass the info so a user can bookmark their request, though it would need to do the validations in the same page as where it shows results. I usually do this with the cakedc search plugin.

Returning to your two options, if you mean which is better in performance i would choose number one, since the second one needs to load a new model/controller etc

Comment: Thanks - If I wanted to use paginate with the results - how would that affect the options?

Comment: if you want to use paginate, you must pass also all the named parameters when calling paginator to print the links and it wont affect. i use the plugin with paginate and it works perfect :)